# Running Python code in Docker gives: "/usr/bin/python3: can't find '__main__' module in 'test.py'"

Tags: python, docker

So I'm trying to run this docker container

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt update
RUN apt install software-properties-common -y
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
RUN apt install python3-pip -y
RUN apt-get remove swig
RUN apt-get install swig3.0
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/swig3.0 /usr/bin/swig
RUN pip3 install auto-sklearn

# During debugging, this entry point will be overridden. For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-debug
ADD . /test.py
WORKDIR /
CMD ["python3", "test.py"]
```

and I get the error "/usr/bin/python3: can't find '**main**' module in 'test.py'" from Docker Desktop. There are other posts similar to this on Stack Overflow, but I made the appropriate changes and it still doesn't seem to work. My Python code is quite simple

```
import pandas as pd
import autosklearn.classification as classification
import sklearn.model_selection as model_selection

if __name__ == "__main__":
    def split_train_val(self, X: pd.DataFrame, y: pd.DataFrame):
        X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = model_selection.train_test_split(
            X, y, test_size=0.25)
        return X_train, X_val, y_train.to_frame(), y_val.to_frame()

    model = classification.AutoSklearnClassifier(
                time_left_for_this_task=3600,
                ensemble_size=1,
                ensemble_nbest=1,
            )

    dataset = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
    dataset = dataset.iloc[:100]
    X, y = dataset.drop(columns=[target_col]), dataset[target_col]
    self.model.fit(X, y)

    print(self.model.cv_results_)
```

Comment: Does it run on your local host successfully?

Comment: @TerrySposato no it does not cause I'm running windows and auto sklearn does not work on windows

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue with a Linux host. It turns out that there was an error in the file path.

This can be checked by opening a shell in the docker container and listing the directory:

```
/validator # ls -l
[...]
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Mar  5 18:51 validateCerberusSchema.py
```

What happens is that when the source file is not found at the given path, docker does not complain. Instead, it creates an empty folder and binds it. Hence in my case, it created a `validateCerberusSchema.py` *folder* on my host and bound it to the `/validator/validateCerberusSchema.py` *folder*. Then python, when trying to run a folder as a script, gives this error: `/usr/local/bin/python3: can't find '__main__' module in '/validator/validateCerberusSchema.py'`.

In the end, the combination of a silent fallback and an unclear error message gives a confused programmer.

In short, fixing the path fixed it!